# ASP.NET MVC can't get Jquery validation to work on form in _layout

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a navbar in my _layout that contains a dropdown, inside this dropdown a partial view is rendered (that contains a login form), despite the JQuery validation scripts being present (via bundle config), and my model having the correct data annotations, the form inputs won't validate, however if the partial is rendered in the body the validation works fine.

I assume then something about the layout (or maybe the form being in a dropdown) is causing the problem.

Important bits of my layout...

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquerybase")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryajax")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Styles.Render("~/Styles/bootstrap")
@Styles.Render("~/Styles/css")


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="MainNavbar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>               
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right float-right">
            @if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login
                    </a>

                    <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdownLogon">
                        @Html.Partial("~/Views/User/Logon.cshtml", new SiteProject.Models.UserModel())
                    </div>
             }
                </li>
         </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

My partialview:

```
@model SiteProject.Models.UserModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Logon", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { htmlAttributes = new { Id = "logonForm", name = "logonForm" } }))
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <form class="px-4 py-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Username", htmlAttributes: new { id = "UserNameLabel" })
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "Username", @class = "form-control", } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Password", htmlAttributes: new { id = "PasswordLabel" })
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "password", id = "Password", @class = "form-control", } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
    </form>
    <br />
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Forgot password?</a>
    </div>

}
```

Can anyone shed light as to why, and what the solution would be.

Thank you.

Comment: Inside this dropdown a partial view is rendered ? Can you add your layout in question.

Comment: Updated the question...